# Magento module not added to core_resource table

Tags: magento

I am trying to write a script which has to execute when a module is updated. I wanted to check the version in db table `core_resource`, but i see now that the module is not added there. Am i looking in the wrong place, or is there something wrong with my code? This is the relevant part of the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mymodule>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </mymodule>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <update_myscript>
                <setup>
                    <module>mymodule</module>
                </setup>
            </update_myscript>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And i created an update file: /updateMyscript/upgrade-1.0.0.0-1.0.0.1.php

Comment: There are a few problems here. **1:** `mymodule` may be an example only, but it's inaccurate because it will never work. It needs a vendor and a package, so example *could be* `my_module` but never `mymodule`. **2:** `upgrade-1.0.0.0-1.0.0.1.php` will only execute once you change your version from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.1 in your config.xml file. You should still have a core_resource entry in the database module though. **3:** Have you got a module registration file in `app/etc/modules/my_module.xml`?

Comment: @RobbieAverill 1. Like you said it is just an example, but thanks anyway for explaining, i didn't know that. 3. I do. I also see my module active in the backend.

Comment: Cool - that eliminates a couple of simple problems :-)

Comment: @RobbieAverill It probably does, but unfortunately not the problem i am facing here.

Answer (score 0):

If your module has been registered on core_resource, you need to delete from that, for the setup execute again.

And if you want update the module setup, you need to create that upgrade file (upgrade-1.0.0.0-1.0.0.1.php) and alter the version on config.xml
Like this:

```
<mymodule>
    <version>1.0.0.1</version>
</mymodule>
```

After this you need clear cache from Magento.

Comment: The problem i am having is that the module does not register on core_resource

Comment: Try activate the developer mode to debug your code, and set breakpoints in upgrade-1.0.0.0-1.0.0.1.php, if possible paste the install file here.